# SQL Server filter table multiple schemas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible when using table filters to define multiple schemas ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry SSMS doesn't do that.  I suppose you could work around this by creating a login that can only view the schemas you want, which you then connect to via the object explorer.  But that sounds a little messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` `Filters` are useful if you have lots of related `tables` and you need only a particular set of them e.g. every `table` with "`user`" in the `table name.`